# Pandas: Fill missing datetime values from another column but increment each replacement if duplicate

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry for the confusing question, I don't know the best way to summarize this into a more descriptive question.

I have a dataframe that has two datetime columns, one just gives just the date and the other adds a specific hour and minute value to the date column, say "Date_Hour_Minute". The Date_Hour_Minute column has lots of missing values but the Date column has none.

```
  Row  |   Date   |  ID   |     Date_Hour_Minute 
==========================================
   1   |   02/21  |  25   |    02/21 06:02    
   2   |   02/21  |  30   |    NA    
   3   |   02/21  |  30   |    NA    
   4   |   02/21  |  25   |    NA    
   5   |   02/21  |  25   |    02/21 07:10      
   6   |   02/21  |  30   |    NA       
   7   |   02/22  |  30   |    NA
```

Now I want to replace all the NA values in the Date_Hour_Minute column with the corresponding Date value with a hour/minute value appended to it. With `fillna` I can easily append a time of midnight to the Date and replace the NA with it

```
df.Date_Hour_Minute = df.Date_Hour_Minute.fillna(df.Date)
```

which results in

```
  Row  |   Date   |  ID   |     Date_Hour_Minute 
============================================
   1   |   02/21  |  25   |    02/21 06:02     
   2   |   02/21  |  30   |    02/21 00:00 
   3   |   02/21  |  30   |    02/21 00:00 
   4   |   02/21  |  25   |    02/21 00:00 
   5   |   02/21  |  25   |    02/21 07:10       
   6   |   02/21  |  30   |    02/21 00:00    
   7   |   02/22  |  30   |    NA
```

However, this creates a lot of duplicates in the Date_Hour_Minute column. Is there a way I can make each replacement unique by adding 1 minute the second time a NA value is encountered then 2 minutes to the next NA value and so on for **a particular ID and date**? (if a new date is seen for that ID then the counter is reset).
So that the result looks like this -

```
  Row  |   Date   |  ID   |     Date_Hour_Minute 
============================================ 
   1   |   02/21  |  25   |    02/21 06:02    
   2   |   02/21  |  30   |    02/21 00:00 
   3   |   02/21  |  30   |    02/21 00:01  (add 1 minute to previous NA value with same date for ID=30) 
   4   |   02/21  |  25   |    02/21 00:00  
   5   |   02/21  |  25   |    02/21 07:10       
   6   |   02/21  |  30   |    02/21 00:02   
   7   |   02/22  |  30   |    02/22 00:00 (reset increment counter because new date for ID=30)
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses a dictionary to hold the next default ime value, keyed by id and date

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO 
from datetime import timedelta

# Test data
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO ("""
Row|Date|ID|Date_Hour_Minute
1|2018-02-21|25|2018-02-21 06:02
2|2018-02-21|30|NA
3|2018-02-21|30|NA
4|2018-02-21|25|NA
5|2018-02-21|25|2018-02-21 07:10
6|2018-02-21|30|NA
7|2018-02-22|30|NA
"""), sep= "|", parse_dates= ["Date", "Date_Hour_Minute"], infer_datetime_format = True)

# Global dictionary to cache the last assigned value by group
last_date = {}

def enhance_date(p):
    """ 
    Expects a triple of Date, Id, Date_Hour_Minute
    Returns the modified Date_Hour_Minute
    """

    # Define the cache
    global last_date

    #Extract the parameters
    date = p[0]
    id = p[1]
    date_hour_minute = p[2]

    # Make a key for the dictionary cache with id and date
    key = str(id) + "|" + str(date) 

    # Apply the rules ans save next value in cache
    if pd.isnull(date_hour_minute):
        if key in last_date:
            r = last_date[key]
            last_date[key] = r + timedelta(minutes=1)
        else:
            r = date
            last_date[key] = r + timedelta(minutes=1)
    else:   
        r = date_hour_minute

    return  r


# Apply to each triple and assign to a new column
df1["New_Date_Hour_Minute"] = df1[["Date", "ID", "Date_Hour_Minute"]].apply(enhance_date, axis=1)

print(df1)
```

Results

```
   Row       Date  ID    Date_Hour_Minute New_Date_Hour_Minute
0    1 2018-02-21  25 2018-02-21 06:02:00  2018-02-21 06:02:00
1    2 2018-02-21  30                 NaT  2018-02-21 00:00:00
2    3 2018-02-21  30                 NaT  2018-02-21 00:01:00
3    4 2018-02-21  25                 NaT  2018-02-21 00:00:00
4    5 2018-02-21  25 2018-02-21 07:10:00  2018-02-21 07:10:00
5    6 2018-02-21  30                 NaT  2018-02-21 00:02:00
6    7 2018-02-22  30                 NaT  2018-02-22 00:00:00
```